# Create a date column from existing date column as one day minus the existing date column

Tags: dax

I have a date column, called `Eff_Date` and a column name `cmg` as below,

```
Eff_Date       cmg
-------------------
15-12-2017     F1
18-12-2018     F1
1-2-2019       F2
```

and I want to create a new Date Column which is one day previous to the date in the next row in  `eff_date` Column as below for a particular `cmg`.

```
Eff_Date        NewDateColumn
-------------------------------
15-12-2017      17-12-2018
18-12-2018      18-12-2018
1-2-2019        1-2-2019
```

the `NewDateColumn` will have (17-12-2018 , as next row in `Eff_date` has 18-12-2018) for `cmg` = F1

The last row will be same as `eff_date` for a particular `cmg`
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a few rows in your table to test for handling of ties:

```
Eff_Date    cmg
12/15/2017  F1
12/18/2018  F1
1/15/2019   F1
1/20/2019   F1
1/22/2019   F1
6/7/2017    F2
8/9/2018    F2
10/10/2018  F2
1/2/2019    F2
1/2/2019    F2
```

While there are many ways to calculate this, I think the most important is that you need to rank the dates in order to identify the next one.

I did this by defining a few variables:

```
=
VAR thisDateRank =
    RANKX (
        FILTER ( Table1, Table1[cmg] = EARLIER ( Table1[cmg] ) ),
        Table1[Eff_Date],
        ,
        ASC
    )
VAR maxDateRank =
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( Table1, Table1[cmg] = EARLIER ( Table1[cmg] ) ),
        Table1[Eff_Date]
    )
VAR nextDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Table1[Eff_Date] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Table1 ),
            Table1[cmg] = EARLIER ( Table1[cmg] )
                && RANKX (
                    FILTER ( Table1, Table1[cmg] = EARLIER ( Table1[cmg] ) ),
                    Table1[Eff_Date],
                    ,
                    ASC
                ) = thisDateRank + 1
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( Table1[Eff_Date] = maxDateRank, maxDateRank, nextDate - 1 )
```

The result looks like this

```
Eff_Date    cmg NewDateColumn
12/15/2017  F1  12/17/2018
12/18/2018  F1  1/14/2019
1/15/2019   F1  1/19/2019
1/20/2019   F1  1/21/2019
1/22/2019   F1  1/22/2019
6/7/2017    F2  8/8/2018
8/9/2018    F2  10/9/2018
10/10/2018  F2  1/1/2019
1/2/2019    F2  1/2/2019
1/2/2019    F2  1/2/2019
```